# ORA-00905: missing keyword Oracle Apex in sql query code editor

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm doing a web app to show some chart and I would like to change color on depending of the value. I'm looking for a way to set different colors from the sql query, but The code editor returns this error message :"ORA-00905: missing keyword"

This is the simple query:

```
select '%' label , 
       apex_504.P3_READ_DATI_NUM('V_OEE',:P3_STRINGA_VIEW) val,
       100 max_value,
       case val when val <= 50 then 'red'
                   when (val >50 and val <=85) then 'yellow'
                   when val > 85 then 'green'
        end as set_color           
from dual;
```

I'm using the case to set a string with the color. I'm going to use set_color to modify the appearence. I would to set the Appereance area in this way

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CASE` is wrong; should be

```
WITH temp
     AS (SELECT apex_504.P3_READ_DATI_NUM ('V_OEE', :P3_STRINGA_VIEW) val
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT '%' label,
       val,
       100 max_value,
       CASE                                                    --> no VAL here
          WHEN val <= 50
          THEN
             'red'
          WHEN (    val > 50
                AND val <= 85)
          THEN
             'yellow'
          WHEN val > 85
          THEN
             'green'
       END
          AS set_color
  FROM temp;
```

Comment: Now I'm getting the error message:"ORA-00904: "VAL": invalid identifier"

Comment: Aha, VAL is actually APEX_504... so you should use that instead of VAL in CASE. In order to simplify it, use a CTE. I modified code I previously posted; have a look, please.

Comment: thank you so much for your solution. The web app works how I wanted.